# Why is the Docusign api retrieving deleted envelopes?

Tags: docusignapi

I am doing a request to retrieve the envelopes completed between some dates like this:

```
{'fromdate': '2020-06-18', 'todate': '2020-06-20', 'status': 'completed'}
```

and it's retrieving some envelopes from 06/18 that already were deleted from docusign dashboard

This is the response:

```
[{'createdDateTime': '2020-06-18 18:12:45', 'sentDateTime': '2020-06-18 18:12:49', 'completedDateTime': '2020-06-18 18:48:54', 'envelopeId': '1ede672a-da54-445b-8546-8967a58fae0f'}, 
{'createdDateTime': '2020-06-18 18:12:41', 'sentDateTime': '2020-06-18 18:12:43', 'completedDateTime': '2020-06-18 18:49:22', 'envelopeId': 'd514d6d4-ec06-467a-a17f-84eae548efb1', 'templateId': ''},
 {'createdDateTime': '2020-06-18 18:12:28', 'sentDateTime': '2020-06-18 18:12:30', 'completedDateTime': '2020-06-18 18:50:36', 'envelopeId': '658a32c2-4980-4fa8-ac09-190a757b2d38', 'templateId': ''},
 {'createdDateTime': '2020-06-18 18:12:19', 'sentDateTime': '2020-06-18 18:12:22', 'completedDateTime': '2020-06-18 18:51:44', 'envelopeId': 'a0d1ce14-44cf-4ffe-ae92-462d567838a9', 'templateId': ''}, 
{'createdDateTime': '2020-06-18 18:13:13', 'sentDateTime': '2020-06-18 18:13:17', 'completedDateTime': '2020-06-18 18:55:13', 'envelopeId': 'e4c8d468-a87c-4bb6-87bb-1ae883b6e85a', 'templateId': ''},
 {'createdDateTime': '2020-06-18 19:12:13', 'sentDateTime': '2020-06-18 19:19:19', 'completedDateTime': '2020-06-18 19:19:19', 'envelopeId': '82247547-178a-4fac-a2e2-ba9521cfeb5f', 'templateId': ''}, 
{'createdDateTime': '2020-06-19 12:05:42', 'sentDateTime': '2020-06-19 12:30:31', 'completedDateTime': '2020-06-19 12:30:31', 'envelopeId': '3e41bf30-e0d5-4c37-9626-347a4d672142', 'templateId': ''}, 
{'createdDateTime': '2020-06-19 12:05:53', 'sentDateTime': '2020-06-19 12:34:02', 'completedDateTime': '2020-06-19 12:34:02', 'envelopeId': '42e33b1d-136c-41cf-b6bc-691414f258f1', 'templateId': ''}, 
{'createdDateTime': '2020-06-19 12:06:03', 'sentDateTime': '2020-06-19 12:38:26', 'completedDateTime': '2020-06-19 12:38:26', 'envelopeId': 'a585acc1-23d4-418c-adb0-5d67073fc49c', 'templateId': ''}, 
{'createdDateTime': '2020-06-19 12:06:39', 'sentDateTime': '2020-06-19 12:53:09', 'completedDateTime': '2020-06-19 12:53:09', 'envelopeId': '34eeac86-08bc-4348-8f11-75cd60862160', 'templateId': ''}]
```

when you can see I only have the 06/19 on my dashboard

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this? Thanks before hand

Comment: how did you delete the envelopes?

Comment: from the dashboard, using the delete option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted envelopes go in the Deleted folder (like "recycle bin" in Windows).
So "deleting" envelopes simply means moving them to another folder.
Using the /folders endpoint (FoldersApi in the SDK) you can get envelopes from specific folders, thus you can avoid deleted items if you so choose.

[They will be gone completely after 24 hours.](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-delete-documents)

Comment: thank you, for your answer, is there anyway to delete it completely?

Comment: wait 24 hours or so